# How to speed up query with aggregates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I have the following query that seems to run pretty slow if more than one aggregate is used in the select part. Is there some way to optimize this?

The query returns a 168 rows and takes 1 second to complete, but this bogs down when a couple of users load the page at once and the original query had more aggregates which also add seconds to the query.

***** Update here's a simplier query**

```
Select 
    gocm.CustomerID,
    sum(DISTINCT o.OrderTotal) as TotalOfOrders
from GroupOrder_Customer_Mapping gocm
    Left Join [Order] o on o.CreatedForCustomerID = gocm.customerid and o.grouporderid = 8254
where gocm.grouporderid = 8254
    group by gocm.CustomerID, invitePath
    order by invitepath
```

**Execution Plan**

[image]

**returns following data (sample results)**
[image]

Comment: Can you include the execution plan?

Comment: What does `SUM(DISTINCT OrderTotal)` mean? If two people placed orders for $10 you should only count one of them?

Comment: Why are you doing left joins instead of inner joins?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrant - good point...

Comment: @Dan Bracuk - It's to display customer names for all customers even ones who do not have an order

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I suspect the OP was hoping it'd be `DISTINCT` per-customer - which still isn't likely to be correct, as I can envision a number of situations where there are multiple orders for the same customer with the same total.  @chobo - I'm anticipating you have a duplicate you need to get rid of - we're going to need to see some sample data to be able to eliminate it.

Comment: Oh no - EAV for customer properties like FirstName and LastName. Why aren't these just stored in the customer table? Do you envision having a ton of nameless customers?

Comment: I've updated to a simplier query that still highlights the performance issue. I tried without the distinct and I guess the way the tables or orders are setup it actually needs it otherwise the totals are messed up (way too big)

Comment: @chobo First tell us what you want your query to return, because I don't think your query makes sense.

Comment: Could you show the used indexes, please?

Comment: @Alexander - Where can I find that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
SELECT 
      gocm.CustomerID
    , o.TotalOfOrders 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT gocm.CustomerID, invitePath
    FROM dbo.GroupOrder_Customer_Mapping gocm
    WHERE gocm.grouporderid = 8254
) gocm 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
          o.CreatedForCustomerID
        , TotalOfOrders = SUM(DISTINCT o.OrderTotal) 
    FROM dbo.[Order] o
    WHERE o.grouporderid = 8254
    GROUP BY o.CreatedForCustomerID
) o ON o.CreatedForCustomerID = gocm.customerid 
ORDER BY invitepath
```

Comment: This made it almost instant! Thank you. I was leaning toward a subquery in the Left join but couldn't get it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

If data is not updated frequently you might consider an [indexed view](https://www.google.sk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiQtovqrPXWAhWObFAKHYCADqAQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fsql%2Frelational-databases%2Fviews%2Fcreate-indexed-views&usg=AOvVaw2qg8JUjRS_EWeumVLVhXpE).